# Rust: How to filter out "None" emissions?

Tags: rust, iterator

My use-case is that I want to scan over an iterator, and yield accumulated values over segments of the original iterator (this is for a tokenizer). In other words, it's not a 1-to-1 mapping between the input values and output values. Note that `filter_map()` won't work because I do need the accumulator value.

I found `.scan()`, which is *almost* what I want:

```rust
#![allow(unused)]
fn main() {
    let a = [1, 2, 3];
    
    let mut iter = a.iter().scan(1, |state, &x| {
        if x == 2 {
            return None;
        }
    
        // each iteration, we'll multiply the state by the element
        *state = *state * x;
    
        // then, we'll yield the negation of the state
        Some(-*state)
    });
    
    println!("{:?}", &iter.next());
    println!("{:?}", &iter.next());
    println!("{:?}", &iter.next());
}
```

Except that the above outputs

```
Some(-1)
None
Some(-3)
```

When I want it to output

```
Some(-1)
Some(-3)
None
```

And, despite what you might think, this doesn't work:

```rust
        Some(-*state)
    }).filter(|x| x.is_some());
```

Because I'm not actually iterating over `Option`s:

```
error[E0599]: no method named `is_some` found for reference `&{integer}` in the current scope
  --> src/main.rs:15:21
   |
15 |     }).filter(|x| x.is_some());
   |                     ^^^^^^^ method not found in `&{integer}`
```

So it's like iterator methods are intentionally shielded from the "missing yield value" case.

Any ideas how I can a) filter out those missing yields, or b) accomplish the above in some totally different way?

Comment: In this case you could just put a filter before the scan `let mut iter = a.iter().filter(|&&x| x!=2 ).scan(1, |state, &x| {..})` but I assume your real situation is more complex?

Comment: Yes, I may have made a bad example. What I'm wanting to do is tokenize some code, so for example go from ['l', 'e', 't', ' ', 'f', 'o', 'o', ' ', '='] to ["let", "foo", "="]. So the input values will end up "grouped up" into a smaller number of output values. This could be accomplished with .scan(), if I could just return None when I don't have a full token yet and then not have those manifest in the resulting iterator.

Comment: You might want to take a look into [`group_by`](https://docs.rs/itertools/0.9.0/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.group_by) from the itertools crate, which seems designed for such use case.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `filter_map` and make your own accumulator in a variable outside the iterator:

```rust
fn main() {
    let a = [1, 2, 3];

    let mut state = 1;

    let mut iter = a.iter().filter_map(|&x| {
        if x == 2 {
            return None;
        }

        // each iteration, we'll multiply the state by the element
        state = state * x;

        // then, we'll yield the negation of the state
        Some(-state)
    });

    println!("{:?}", &iter.next()); // Some(-1)
    println!("{:?}", &iter.next()); // Some(-3)
    println!("{:?}", &iter.next()); // None
}
```

Comment: Yes, I ended up doing almost the same thing but using scan(); I just double-wrap the values in Option<> and then filter afterward. A little bit clunkier, but avoids external state. I don't feel great about either variation on this strategy but it gets the job done.

Answer (score 0):

Just printing 3 `iter.next()` should be a very uncommon use case. Mostly one would loop until `None` or use a function like `fuse` or `collect` on the iterator. Each of these functions cuts all results after the first `None`. So returning `None` from an iterator means: terminate the iterator.

Consequently you should avoid to terminate the iterator in your scan closure, e.g.

```
    let mut iter = a.iter().scan(1, |state, &x| {
        if x == 2 {
            return Some(None); // continue, but without value
        }
    
        // each iteration, we'll multiply the state by the element
        *state = *state * x;
    
        // then, we'll yield the negation of the state
        Some(Some(-*state)) // continue with value
    }).flatten(); // remove all missing values
```

or by separating the scan from the filter:

```
let mut iter = a
    .iter()
    .scan(1, |state, &x| {
      if x == 2 {
        return Some((x, *state));
      }

      // each iteration, we'll multiply the state by the element
      *state = *state * x;

      // then, we'll yield the negation of the state
      Some((x, -*state))
    })
    .filter_map(|(x, state)| if x == 2 { None } else { Some(state) });
```

Comment: Since it *never* returns `None` from `scan()`, the code isn't making use of the ability of `scan` to terminate iteration. It could use `filter_map` as shown by Coder-256, and avoid `Some(Some(...))`.

Comment: This solution aims to avoid state that is external to the iterator (a pure functional approach). I added another variant how to achieve this. What is wrong with `Some(Some(...))`, apart from looking strange?

Comment: Nothing inherently wrong with `Option<Option<T>>`, it's just that the single `Option<T>` is simpler to understand and reason about. The former could also be a bit slower depending on how smart the optimizer is in this case. Avoiding external state is also nice (though still not purely functional, as the closure _mutates_ the state), so I guess it's a matter of taste. `filter_map` seems simpler, is used more often and I'd prefer it to `scan` whenever I can get away with it.

Comment: My goal is specifically for it *not* to terminate before all of the above results are done. The explicit use of .next() was just for illustration. I may not have made that clear enough.